# How to create customer attribute progrmatically in magento (not from setup script)

Tags: magento-1.9, import, csv, customer-attribute

I have csv with customer attributes .

there is a button in the admin side.
when i click that button it should read csv & create all attrbutes in that csv.

I have idea to read csv file.but I'm not able to get syntax to create customer attributes programtically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup` which eventually inherits from `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup`; this class implements the `addAttribute` method which you can use to add your attributes programmatically. This is actually the same class that used in the upgrade scripts.

```
$setup = Mage::getModel('customer/entity_setup');
// Example of how to add a customer attribute
$setup->addAttribute('customer', $attributeCode, array(
    'type'      => 'int',
    'label'     => 'Some Label',
    'input'     => 'boolean',
    'backend'   => 'customer/attribute_backend_data_boolean',
    'position'  => 32,
    'required'  => false
));
```

Another method of interest is `_prepareValues` which is called by `addAttribute`; this method handles the mapping between the format you need to feed `addAttribute` and the format needed by the DB:

```
protected function _prepareValues($attr)
{
    $data = array(
        'backend_model'   => $this->_getValue($attr, 'backend'),
        'backend_type'    => $this->_getValue($attr, 'type', 'varchar'),
        'backend_table'   => $this->_getValue($attr, 'table'),
        'frontend_model'  => $this->_getValue($attr, 'frontend'),
        'frontend_input'  => $this->_getValue($attr, 'input', 'text'),
        'frontend_label'  => $this->_getValue($attr, 'label'),
        'frontend_class'  => $this->_getValue($attr, 'frontend_class'),
        'source_model'    => $this->_getValue($attr, 'source'),
        'is_required'     => $this->_getValue($attr, 'required', 1),
        'is_user_defined' => $this->_getValue($attr, 'user_defined', 0),
        'default_value'   => $this->_getValue($attr, 'default'),
        'is_unique'       => $this->_getValue($attr, 'unique', 0),
        'note'            => $this->_getValue($attr, 'note'),
        'is_global'       => $this->_getValue($attr, 'global', 1),
    );

    return $data;
}
```